# Function getting og:image

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I'm using wordpress and have function which return og:image:

```
$url = 'http://www.abcd.com'; / the_field('link');
$page_content = file_get_contents($url);

$dom_obj = new DOMDocument();
@$dom_obj->loadHTML($page_content);
$meta_val = null;

foreach($dom_obj->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {

if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image'){ 

    $meta_val = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}
}
echo '<img src="'.$meta_val.'" style="width:180px; height:auto;" />';
```

It works fine when i paste manually into $url the site url, but i want to use **the_field('link')** (getting form Advanced Custom fields) which get me url but the function return error:

file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have read this document, `the_field()` seems to return `echo get_field();`.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

So I think you need to set `get_field()` value to `$url` value.

```
$url = get_field('link');
```